# Error when clipping raster in QGIS: "'ascii' codec can't encode character"?

Tags: qgis, gdal, error, ascii, encoding

I have done it many times (clipping a raster with a polygon layer or by extension) but today I got an error for the first time and I don't know how to solve it. I am always using the same type of raster layers. When running the clipping tool I got the following message:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -projwin 410282.185971 4694950.41162 410783.882475 4694524.96815 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 -co TFW=YES "C:/Users/FERRAN ALA/Desktop/Justificació Fontanals/QGIS/Topo 1_5000/bt5mv20sd0f283077st1r031.sid" "C:/Users/FERRAN ALA/Desktop/Justificació Fontanals/QGIS/background/image.tif"
```

GDAL command output:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 201: ordinal not in range(128) See log for more details

Does anybody know what that is?

Comment: You should not use characters with accent mark (typical of catalan) and spaces in your paths. Probably, it is the source of your issues.

Comment: Please, see this link referred to unicode xf3 character: http://www.codetable.net/hex/f3

Comment: Hello, thank you for that information. I removed all accents and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

User xunilk [nailed it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308109/error-when-clipping-raster-in-qgis#comment498777_308109): the error message is saying that the unicode character `xf3` (which is the `ó` from `Justificació`) could not be encoded (i.e. altered from unicode to a string).

As you already figured out, remove such type of characters (with accent marks) from file paths and file names. Remove the spaces as well:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -projwin 410282.185971 4694950.41162 410783.882475 4694524.96815 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 -co TFW=YES "C:/Users/FERRAN_ALA/Desktop/Justificacio_Fontanals/QGIS/Topo_1_5000/bt5mv20sd0f283077st1r031.sid" "C:/Users/FERRAN_ALA/Desktop/Justificaci0_Fontanals/QGIS/background/image.tif"
```

Comment: C'mon, we're not in the 90's anymore. So GDAL will never know how to use UTF-8? Who they think they are? Microsoft?!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use the Chinese characters, I had this problem before. And after deleting the file with Chinese characters, it run successful.

Answer (score -2):

*## import this*

conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).